# Whats it called when you fit a linear regression to data with outliers at the end point that influence your regression

Tags: regression, outliers, linear, leverage

So if you have outliers in the middle of your sample it doesn't influence your regression much but if they are at either end of your sample they do.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the word you are looking for is [leverage.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_%28statistics%29)